# Thunderbird resets profile after second start up

Tags: 14.04, permissions, thunderbird, email, partitioning

The issue is as follows:

After cleanly reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, I set up my thunderbird profile (using the profile manager), which I store on a separate ext4 partition (I am owner of this partition after using chmod to take ownership with chmod nls:nls /path).

After I fire up thunderbird for the first time, all my folders, rules and accounts show up as expected. Everything works fine.

However, once I close thunderbird and come back to it later, everything disappears, and TB asks me if I'd like to create a new email (it seems to be starting tb as root, as the suggested email is root, not nls).

The profile.ini within the .thunderbird folder of my home drive points to my mail folder on the separate partition.

As you can see here:

```
    [General]
    StartWithLastProfile=1

    [Profile0]
    Name=default
    IsRelative=1
    Path=hn3xusic.default

    [Profile1]
    Name=Default User
    IsRelative=0
    Path=/media/dataHive/Mail/hn3xusic.default
    Default=1
```

Now what confuses me the most is, that even if I remove TB using software center, and delete the .thunderbird folder in /home, and reinstall it, the error keeps happening - without it working at all (first startup doesnt show my emails/rules/folders anymore).

Is this some kind of problem with permissions or access of files?

My fstab looks as follows:

```
    # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
    # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
    UUID=d20689ef-0113-454a-a015-5a7fc370d9fd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
    #[...]
    # /media/dataHive was on /dev/sda7 during installation
    UUID=345cb53c-78f1-46e0-a312-360d89797a0f /media/dataHive ext4    defaults        0       2
```

If you need anything else to identify the issue, I'll gladly comply.

**Update**

I have reinstalled ubuntu to trace back my steps as to how this happens.
This time I did not format my data partition, leaving as it is, since I believe the problem being related to file access permissions.

Here's what I did:
1. Install ubuntu 14.04 LTS from usb (formated / partition, left all others as were)
2. Updated ubuntu via software updater
3. Made sure I own the /media/dataHive partition using the command
        sudo chown -R nls:nls /media/dataHive
4. Started thunderbird, clicked "I will configure my Account later.", closed TB again
5. started thunderbird with 'thunderbird -p' and created a new profile, pointing to
        /media/dataHive/mail/xxxx.default*
*note that xxxx was the same number as the folder name that was created in   /home/.thunderbird after I started TB in step 4.
6. Saw that nothing was imported / loaded.

Even when I modify my profile.ini to show only one path it doesn't load anything:
        [General]
        StartWithLastProfile=1

```
    [Profile0]
    Name=default
    IsRelative=0
    Path=/media/dataHive/Mail/5i1ehrtc.default
    Default=1
```

**Update 2**
I created a new partition and mounted it under /mnt/mail.
I chown'ed it from root to me, and additionally made sure I have access & execution permissions by using the chmod cmd (chmod ug+rwx /dir).
Still not working. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I apparently 'fixed' my issue, and it is apparently (?) a problem with compatibility between Ubuntu versions.
OR
An issue with logical partitions.

I have repeated my steps as described above again, this time I used ubuntu 14.10 instead though (as I remember having that version installed before 14.04LTS):

1. completely formatted the drive using gparted
   (this time, I put the mail partition in a primary partition, instead of a logical one.)
2. Installed Ubuntu 14.10
3. Chown'ed the partitions to belong to me instead of root.
4. Started TB, quit it, renamed the folder on my mail partition to be the same as the one in my Home folder (just as described in the [tutorial on how to move your TB profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder))
5. Started TB with the profile manager enabled and created a new profile pointing to my mail partition's email folder

Unfortunately I didn't realize that I may have altered two variables, instead of one, so the **answer to this question may be one of the two:**

1. Thunderbird Profiles cannot be moved from a newer Ubuntu Version to an older one (or in the very least not from 14.10 to 14.04 LTS)
2. Thunderbird doesn't like its mail profiles on logical partitions.

Either of them seem unlikely to me, however I am a novice in all matters Linux/ubuntu, so an answer from an experienced user may give more insight.

Eitherway, my profile now starts regularly and completely everytime now, after making the above changes.